# Can I implement MRZ Reading of ID Card Or Passport in Expo managed react native project?

Tags: react-native, expo, scanning, mrz

I have a problem/issue with finding any useful sdk, which is capable to work as MRZ reader.
I want to read mrz from ID Card or from Passport.
Is it possible to be done on expo?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I want to do that too but i can't find any library.

Answer (score 0):

Currently implementing it as part of my IT certification training, I will publish it on GitHub when finished. For starters, please take a look at the below libraries:

- [expo-camera](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/camera/)
- [react-native-tesseract-ocr](https://github.com/jonathanpalma/react-native-tesseract-ocr)
- [Tesseract.js](https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js)

However, you cannot use `Tesseract` natively with Expo at the moment. Please read the related [issue](https://github.com/jonathanpalma/react-native-tesseract-ocr/issues/30) on GitHub.

Best possible way is via ejecting. I will update this post when possible.